# Would ommiting href="en-GB" from the head force a colud server to use $ instead of £?

Tags: asp.net, server, cloud

We have a client site (ASP - Which I have ZERO exerience in) that has recently switched to a cloud server.

Previously it was working perfectly and basket totals were displaying in '£'. Since moving to a cloud server the totals are in '$'. Nothing has been changed in the code and as far as I am aware the code does not know you are dealing with currency. You have to prepend the type of currency you are using in the output.

My question is - Does leaving out lang="en-GB" in the head couse this sort of fallback on the server? Apparently language and location settings are correct when speaking to our provider.

Comment: Difficult to say. The question is rather broad. But I'd start by adding `<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />` in the Web.Config, in the `<system.web>` node.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I have little to know knowledge in the area but your suggestion does sound like something we have spotted on the server that can be modified. Will start there and keep it posted.